# What is the reason to use process.env.NODE_ENV and process.env.ENV variables in angular2?

Tags: node.js, angular

I am starting to learn angular2 and I see that in examples they override process.env.NODE_ENV and process.env.ENV variables in configuration file. This code is from webpack.prod.js from [this example](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/webpack.html)

```
// webpack.prod.js
const ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV = process.env.ENV = 'production';
```

What is the reason for overriding process.env.NODE_ENV and process.env.ENV variables. Is there something in nodejs or in angular 2 that use this variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not something that is only about angular2. When you want to expose env vars from server to client, generally the best practices is to map them with slightly different names and only expose those items that concern the client.

This is so one can not simply look at your API endpoint that exposes env vars and workout all your server env vars.

In this particular example, it also makes sense from the domain perspective. As eventhough process.env.ENV might have the same value as NODE_ENV it does not represent the node.js's environment but the ENV in which angular is running.

It effectively from then on is process.env.NG_ENV or process.env.ENV

Answer (score 2):

One of the simplest use case would be to define the dev mode or prod mode wen bootstraping the app :

```
if ( 'development' === ENV && HMR === true ) {
    // activate hot module reload
    let ngHmr = require( 'angular2-hmr' );
    ngHmr.hotModuleReplacement( main , module );
} else {
     enableProdMode(); // which run Angular2 app in production mode 
}
```

So in general , we can use them in a lot of different scenarios where you want to pass a variable from server ( i.e command-line  ) to your app.